# How to fill missing or empty values based on previous and future values?

Tags: r

Suppose I have following dataset

```
ID A 
1  0
1  0
1  0
1  X
2  X
2  X
2  0
2  X
3  X
3  0
3  X
3  Y
4  X
4  X
4  0
4  Y
```

I want to fill this dataset (variable A) based on past and future values of A.
For example for `ID= 1` first three values will become X too based on future value. For `ID=2`, missing value will become X because past and future values are also X. For `ID = 3` it will also become X even in future there is another value Y but its  adjacent values are X so it will become X. For `ID= 4` we will base missing values only on past.

Basically, the algorithm should look at the past values first; if no past value is available then it should use the future values.

I know about filling the missing values based on mean and median but as variable A is not numeric and the criterion keeps on changing at each step, how should I tackle this problem?

Comment: How do you know if you want to use the future or the past value to replace a missing value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `na.locf` from `zoo` to fill the missing values with the previous values.  To do that, we convert the '0' values to 'NA'.  Using `data.table`, we can convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'ID' column, we fill the missing values with previous non-missing value using `na.locf` and the `na.rm=FALSE` option.  Then, we can again run `na.locf` with `fromLast=TRUE` option to cause observations to be carried backward and fill the remaining `NAs` in 'A' column.

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
is.na(df1$A) <- df1$A==0
setDT(df1)[,A := na.locf(na.locf(A, na.rm=FALSE), fromLast=TRUE) , by = ID]
df1
#    ID A
# 1:  1 X
# 2:  1 X
# 3:  1 X
# 4:  1 X
# 5:  2 X
# 6:  2 X
# 7:  2 X
# 8:  2 X
# 9:  3 X
#10:  3 X
#11:  3 X
#12:  3 Y
#13:  4 X
#14:  4 X
#15:  4 X
#16:  4 Y
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), A = c("0", "0", "0", "X", "X", "X", 
"0", "X", "X", "0", "X", "Y", "X", "X", "0", "Y")), .Names = c("ID", 
"A"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```